# Use RxView.clicks (subscribe does not work)

Tags: android, rx-android

I am new to reactive programming (RxJava and RxAndroid). I want to use RxView.clicks() instead of a click Listener. I put a Button into main layer and with Butterknife and in onCreate method Main activity I write this statement:

```
**//onCreate**
ButterKnife.bind(this);

RxView.clicks(btn_range)
       .switchMap(new Function<Object, Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> apply(Object o) throws Exception {
                return Observable.range(1,10);
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
             @Override
             public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                 d.dispose();
             }

             @Override
             public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, integer+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
     });
```

but when I run it, no toast appears.

I have converted my click listener to an observable and then I have changed the observable to a range of integer and finally I display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.subscribe()` the `Observer<Integer>` calls `d.dispose()` as soon as it is subscribed.

So if your chain is disposed then it is not working anymore. The `Disposable` should be disposed when you no longer need the flow.

You could store the emitted `Disposable` and dispose it in the opposite lifecycle event callback to where you have subscribed it.